# What is the best way to draw lines and circles in a recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to create lines and circle and set their positions relative to the elements in the recyclerview. The result should look like this picture:

[image]

I am talking about the long line with circles and textViews in it. The gradient isn't important.

The card elements with the pictures is inside a recyclerview and they are therefore created by using an adapter.

What i have tried to do, is creating a constraint layout and position the elements to fit the picture. So i have a line 1 (above circle), circle, textView and line 2 (below circle). However, this does not seem like an ideal solution because it is kinda messy.

Is there any other better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

**This will be how your cardview looks like**

1. You will draw linear layout for line 1 in my screenshot, it will have width 2dp and height you want.
2. below it draw this circle.
3. Below the circle put textview.
4. Below textView add line 2, it will be same with line 1.

**All this will be in LinearLayout and next to it put cardview which contains only imageview.**

Inside your onBindView() method in adapter, you will check if it's the first card, hide first line, and so on for colors.

Comment: I have done something similar and it turned out pretty good. However, i just used a constraint layout and set the constraints to match the picture. The code wasn't as messy as i thought it would be.